# Fetch Data from Postgresql into a word processing software (word, indesign)

Tags: postgresql, ms-word, postgis, qgis, adobe-indesign

We store an manipulate geodata in postgresql(postgis) and use QGIS to view and edit.

My team and I need to build reports around that data. The reports are quite text heavy and need some good visual formatting. My colleagues are used to MSword or adobe indesign, so we agreed to use one of these two programs to build our final reports.

Our documents will include around 10 indesign/MSword tables. The data for these tables lives in dedicated views in the pg database. The Tables inside the reports should grow with the underlying data when I do my editing. So that everyone can focus on "their" work and to reduce data redundancy.

What would be the best way to do this?

- I looked at some (ODBC) catalog plugins for indesign but i'm not
  really sure if this is the way to go.
- I'm no developer. I need to learn/look into the respective technologies involved anyway
  so I wanted to define my tech-stack first (maybe hire someone to do it properly).

Maybe someone can give me a general idea / point me in the right direction with this.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi devour, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your questions is not really suitable for this forum, please check out how to ask a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't know if there are some ODBC plugins in the wild. But if you able to export all the relevant data from your system in any text based format (JSON, XML, etc) the data can be loaded into InDesign and the layout can be updated with a script. This is a quite common task actually. But the layout should be designed and tweaked very carefully if you want to fill it with dynamic data via a script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.